# What is this box on wall in my kitchen?

Tags: phone-wiring

This little box is on the kitchen wall of a house I recently bought. House built in the 60s. I'm guessing it's something to do with the phone line but wanted to verify before removing.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the old type of phone jack.

Can probably add the new type of plug, or remove if you do not need it.

Was used with rotary phones.

Comment: Thanks. Found it on Amazon still even: https://www.amazon.com/Allen-Tel-AT404B-Plastic-Telephone/dp/B006J4IGAC/

Comment: Bell System 404A, as best as a quick search will indicate. Not limited to rotary era. BUt that one actually says it's a 404B, so it is. Not clear on the A/B difference.

Comment: Yep, that's an old style phone outlet.  If you still have a landline and it's still connected, there are plug in adapters to convert to RJ11  (currently a typical outlet) for new phones.